# Is there a DWG geometry type that cannot be expressed using WKT?

Tags: well-known-text, dwg

Is there a geometry type (both 2D and 3D) that is supported by DWG and cannot (lossless-ly) be expressed using Well-Known Text? If there is, please provide an example.

Comment: Can you give us a list of DWG geometry types?

Answer (score 1):

It likely depends on the software you intend to use.  If you use AutoCad Map 3D, then:

[About New Polygon and MultiPolygon Features](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-C3DFB6D4-D1C9-428F-BBB4-4D3C2DE38296-htm.html) explains about Polygons and Multipolygons.  It identifies that you cannot create non-planar polygons.

[About LineString and MultiLineString Features](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-1C8CF47D-137D-4D41-8158-A9F550394D83-htm.html) explains about Lines and Multilines.  It identifies some concern for arcs.

[About Point and MultiPoint Features](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-81623982-A60E-470A-BD74-1A7FE40BA9FC-htm.html) doesn't list any issues with Points or Multipoints.